# Minimum spanning trees on two graphs with some common edges

Tags: algorithm, graph, tree, minimum-spanning-tree, undirected-graph

Given two complete graphs with weighted edges, I would like to find two minimum spanning trees (MST) on the two graphs, respectively, under the constraint that the two learned MSTs have common edges on a given subset of edges. Note that the two graphs has same number of vertices but the edge weights are all different.

For example, if the two graphs are complete edge-weighted graphs with vertices {1,...,d}. We require the two learned MSTs has same edges on the complete subgraphs with vertices {1,...,d/2}.

What algorithm can I use to find such MSTs? I tried using a modification of Kruskal's algorithm, but wasn't able to make it work.

Comment: Can you show us the code you used?

Comment: The input is the weight w(i_k,j_k) for any vertices i, j in {1,...,d}, and k=1,2 indicating the two graphs. It is required that the two MSTs has same edges on the complete subgraphs on vertices {1,...,d/2}. I am not sure what algorithm would work. My current thought is to apply Kruskal's algorithm on the weights \sum_{k=1}^2 w(i_k,j_k) for i,j in {1,...,d/2}, and w(i_k,j_k) for i>d/2 or j>d/2. But there exist cases that this algorithm does not guarantee the optimal solution.

Comment: Could you give an complete example?

Comment: I know how to find whether there is or isn't a second MST which matches a first MST on a set of edges, you could have a lot of different MSTs which have different sets of edges on the subgraph of interest.  This has a certain NP-complete feel about it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I got the problem because the description lacks some important details.
Anyway, here is a possible approach with the given constraints for it to be applayable.

As long as two graphs have the same number of edges and you can represent those graphs as lists of edges, the MRT algorithm can be used to find all their common spanning trees.
It is commonly referred to as the *Two Graphs Common Spanning Trees Algorithm* and it's described in an academic article of Mint, Read and Tarjan.
Note that the Boost Graph Library already contains a [proper implementation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/graph/doc/two_graphs_common_spanning_trees.html).

Once you have found those trees, you can iterate over them to drop the ones that are not minimum spanning trees for their respective graphs. Note that if you drop the *i-th* common spanning tree for the first graph, you should as well drop the *i-th* tree of the second graph.
After that, in case the set is not empty, you can drop all those trees that don't contain the given subset of edges that are part of your problem (I didn't fully understand what you mean saying that an edge is in common to two graphs, but if it's a constraint you can enforce it on the resulting set).
The remaining trees are the ones you are looking for.

If the two graphs haven't the same number of edges, you can add fake nodes and edges to the smaller one.
In other terms, create a fake node *nf-i* and add an edge *nf-i -> n-i*, where *n-i* is a real node. Give to the edge a null weight.
At the end of the process, you can easily remove those nodes and edges and get back the original spanning trees.